# mySQL UPDATE TEXT vs INT field types (speed performance)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to UPDATE an undetermined number (max: 32 nos) of random int/float numbers in a mySQL table.

**In PHP I have got them in an array:**

```
$array['numbers'][1]=5.5;
$array['numbers'][2]=2;
$array['numbers'][3]=43;
(...)
```

**mySQL Scenario 1:**

```
+----+-----------------------------------+
| id | numbers(Text)                     |
+----+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | a:3:{i:1;d:5.5;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:43;} |
+----+-----------------------------------+
```

**mySQL Scenario 2:**

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+---
| id | no1(int)   | no2(int)   | no3(int)   |  
+----+------------+------------+------------+---
|  1 | 5.5        | 2          | 43         |
+----+------------+------------+------------+---
```

To update these fields in both scenarios I know the id (which is INT auto_increment) so I will include WHERE id=$known_id

Does it make any difference in terms of **UPDATE** speed, if I serialize these and update the scenario 1 ? Or whether is the scenario 2 significantly faster bear in mind it could be 12, 13, 14, or more fields ?

*Note: I could also separate these by spaces and use implode() / explode() but the question remains the same. Also, I am focused in UPDATE which means am not looking for speed performance for SELECT, etc.*

**EDIT:**

The database is from the same host server and I expect to update about 5 to 50 rows every 10 seconds or so. Also, let's reduce the number of random int numbers to 12, so we can fix the serialized string with between 512 to 1024 chars.

Comment: Well, if you want to know for sure, you can benchmark it. In terms of database structure, neither are very normalized. In performance my guess would be that there is little difference. The biggest gain will be to add an index to `id`.

Comment: Yes, it is indexed and it is unique as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably won't make a significant difference in performance whether you store a serialized array or multiple columns, unless you have very high traffic and long strings.

The cases where it would make any measurable difference are when your array is so long that the serialized string doesn't fit on a single database page. InnoDB automatically finds extra page(s) to store the remainder of the string, but that means more page loads, more disk seeks, etc. To avoid overflow pages, the serialized string would have to be 768 bytes or less (see [Blob Storage in Innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) for full explanation of this).

Another consideration is when you have a very long string and you need to post the whole string just to update a single member of the array. Those bytes have to travel across the network somehow, and there's no way to post only a substring when you use the serialized-array approach. The longer your strings, the more overhead there is to doing an UPDATE. Eventually if you have a lot of these updates executing concurrently, you could use up all your network bandwidth.

For example, a gigabite network (1000Mbit/s) has a throughput of about 112 MB/s. If your strings average 100KB, and you have 1125 concurrent updates per second, that's all of your bandwidth, even on a fast, dedicated network. That doesn't even count other traffic on the same network.

---

Re your comment and update:

Sounds like the number of updates and the average string length are quite modest. Not great enough for this to be a bottleneck. If you connect using the loopback TCP/IP interface (127.0.0.1) then you don't have to worry about bandwidth.

Comment: Helpfull! Bill, please check my edited question. Rgrds and thanks.